# How to specify output folder for T4 file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, t4

I noticed in Visual Studio, that in the properties for a `T4` file, there is a 'Copy to Output directory option'. I have selected the "Copy if newer option", which is the behavior I would like for the generated output of the T4 file.

However, there is no property to specify the output directory for the `T4` file. How do I specify the output directory in Visual Studio for a `T4` file?

Answer (score 2):

I think that option relates to publishing, and will apply to the template itself.

In order to manage the output locations of my T4 templates, I use [T4Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) which has a `Template` class which has an `Output.File` property.